# Python3 pairing urllib.request.Request and BaseHTTPRequestHandler always leading to timeout

Tags: http, python-requests, http-post, urllib

I have a simple pair of Http server/client on my local machine.

On the server side

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
class SampleHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):
        print('Posted!')
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
httpd = HTTPServer(('localhost', 8000), SampleHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

On the client side

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
req = urllib.request.Request(url='http://localhost:8000', method='POST')
t0 = datetime.now()
reader = urllib.request.urlopen(req, timeout=2)
print('Received', datetime.now() - t0)
```

The client side always timeout but receives everything the server replied. It would take a long time if I am to post multiple requests sequentially while ensuring each is received by getting a response.

What am I missing?